# Не работает обработчик наведение мышки

Tags: javascript

Есть три блока планов (Basic, Pro и Premium) необходимо сделать подсвечивание заголовка блока и кнопки "Buy now" по наведению ТОЛЬКО лишь на кнопку buy now. а не на весь блок.

Пробую с первым блоком, событие наведение мыши "onmouseover" не работает, если поставить вместо него "click" начинает работать. Не пойму почему???

```js
var planHover = (function() {

 var basic = document.querySelector(".basic");
 var buy = document.querySelector(".buy");

 buy.addEventListener("onmouseover",
  function () {
   buy.style.backgroundColor = "#49cbcd";
   basic.style.backgroundColor = "#49cbcd";
  });

})();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "OpenSansRegular";
  color: #484c55;
}

.wrapper .section_plans {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table thead th button {
  font-size: 26px;
  background-color: #485460;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 370px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table thead td {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table tbody td {
  color: #8c9299;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 370px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table tfoot td {
  width: 370px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

.wrapper .section_plans .plan table tfoot td button {
  background-color: #485460;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
          border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: "OpenSansSemiBold";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section_plans">
          <div class="plan">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <button class="basic">Basic</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>$5.01 / Month</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Consectetur adipisicing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Nihil repellendus</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Excepturi quod</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Odit repellat</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="buy">Buy now</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div><!-- // plan -->
          <div class="plan">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                  <button>Pro</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>$10.01 / Month</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Consectetur adipisicing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Nihil repellendus</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Excepturi quod</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Odit repellat</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td><button>Buy now</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div><!-- // plan -->
          <div class="plan">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <button>Premium</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>$20.01 / Month</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Consectetur adipisicing</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Nihil repellendus</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Excepturi quod</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Odit repellat</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <td><button>Buy now</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div><!-- // plan -->
        </div><!-- // section_plans -->
     </div><!-- // wrapper -->
    
 <script src="js/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что надо `mouseover`, а не `onmouseover`

Comment: ТОЧНО, ВОТ Я ГОНЮ )))))